# Very simple PowerShell script is not working for unknown reason

Tags: powershell, location

I'm trying to set my current script to the executing path. There I'm reading available JSON files. My `app.exe` list all available JSON files. When I launch this script from `C:\my\proj`. It shows my home path as `C:\Users\EIM`. What is wrong with the following script? Even if I debug it, I can see `$cureentDir` value is `C:\my\proj`. I'm using Windows 10 and PowerShell version 5.

```
$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path;
$cureentDir = Split-Path $scriptpath;
Set-Location -Path $cureentDir;
$exe = "C:\proj\app.exe"
$arguments = '- silent'
Push-Location (Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent)
$proc = [Diagnostics.Process]::Start($exe, $arguments)
$proc.WaitForExit();
```

***Updated***

It is working now. But there is a new problem. Both my app and script is at C:\proj\ location. My console app lists all available JSON files for the user to select from the current location. But now the app is listing files from C:\WINDOWS\system32. Why it doesn't list from C:\proj. If I launch it by double click, it shows files from the current location. How to fix this issue

```
Available bootstrap files:
0. C:\WINDOWS\system32\DefaultQuestions.json
1. C:\WINDOWS\system32\nv-vk64.json
Select:
```

Comment: You have an extra space in `'- silent'`

Comment: The question had `-` with `Parent` on a subsequent line. I edited the code to put it back on one line. Please describe what is happening and paste in any error message text. Don't forget `Pop-Location`.

Comment: How *exactly* is your code "not working"? What behavior do you expect, and how does the behavior you actually get differ from that? Please be precise. We're not sitting in front of your computer, so we don't see what you see unless you describe it to us.

Comment: Why do you need `Diagnostics.Process` `Start` method to run an executable? Why not just run it? `C:\proj\app.exe -silent`

Comment: Well, I tried many ways to keep the process running. But nothing worked for me. So it was one of the little working options.  All it happens just start and stop it immediately. C:\proj\app.exe -silent doesn't work.

Comment: @ Ansgar Wiechers . All I want is that this script starts my console application in a new instance of a console and keep it running until the user terminates it. It simple but it is not working.

Comment: `help Start-Process`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the updated problem, to set my execution directory in current directory following works perfectly. Now my console app looks into the current working directory.

```
[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $PWD
```